# SOAP and Charsets in Java

Tags: java, soap, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

It's more of a 'XML encoding question' - 
I'm trying to send a SOAP request, containing characters from ISO-8859-1 such as 'руддщцщкдв'.

when trying to append it to XML for SOAP requests, it just replaces it all to '?'.

Using [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/), I found out it will work only if I send the value as:

> ```
> <groupName>&#1088;&#1091;&#1076;&#1076;&#1097;&#1094;&#1097;&#1082;&#1076;&#1074;</groupName>
> ```

but I cna't get it to do that using Java Stirng methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the XML document is encoded in UTF-8, not in 8859-1. Try to reencode the string before appending, something like this:

```
new String(yourstring.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") returns an array full of ? (63).
any ideas ?

Comment: `new String(result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"))` with `getBytes` you're getting the raw bytes, not the UTF-8 string.